# Oracle Apex not recognising table that i created

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, ora-00942

I am getting an error with my table named patients. I dropped the table and started again with it and renamed it as below but it is still coming up with and error when I try to insert into the table :

```
Error at line 1/13: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

This is what I have so far:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Details_of_Patient (
  Patient_ID INT,
  PatientFirstName VARCHAR2(50),
  PatientLastName VARCHAR2(50),
  PatientContact VARCHAR2(20),
  PatientAddress VARCHAR2(255),
  PatientGP VARCHAR2(50),
  PatientAlert VARCHAR2(255),
  Appointment_ID INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (Patient_ID)
);

INSERT INTO "Details_of_Patient" ("Patient_ID", "PatientFirstName", "PatientLastName", "PatientDOB", "PatientContact", "PatientAddress", "PatientGP", "PatientAlert", "Appointment_ID")
VALUES 
  ('1', 'John', 'Smith', TO_DATE('22-08-2023', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), '0873456789', '123 Main St', 'Dr. Daly', 'Allergic to Penicillin', '101');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the double quotes. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dFN4LiLJ)

Comment: @MT0 this worked, thank you sooo much, I owe you big time you legend!!!!